# Centrar mermaid en GitHub

Tags: github

He hecho un mermaid en un readme en GitHub y parece que los flowchart si se suelen centrar, pero al hacer un stateDiagram-v2 no parece centrarse, sino que se sitúa a la izquierda.

¿Hay algún método para que se centre el mermaid? Ya sea stateDiagram-v2 como cualquier otro.

Dejo captura de cómo me ha quedado el mermaid:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te sirve algo de lo que comentan acá? https://github.com/mermaid-js/mermaid/issues/150